# Komodo Edit Changes Python sys.path If you "Show in Explorer"

Tags: python, path, module, komodo, komodoedit

I am using [Komodo Edit](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit), a code editor.

When I right click on projects and click "Show in Explorer", it will pop up a box just like Windows Explorer at the directory my project is. This is very convenient.

However, I noticed an insidious side effect. When you try to run a python file with this window that looks exactly like Windows Explorer, you will find out that it completely messes up sys.path in Python to use its own directory.

Is there any way to avoid this?

```
import sys
sys.path

C:\Windows\system32\python26.zip
C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\lib\python\DLLs
C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\lib\python\lib
C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\lib\python\lib\plat-win
C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\lib\python\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python26
C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\lib\python
C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\lib\python\lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\lib\python\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\lib\python\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\lib\python\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a problem in Komodo. It actually stems from the Explorer window spawned by Komodo having the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable set to include Komodo's path, since the child process inherits the parent's environment. I noticed this by opening a Command Prompt window through an Explorer spawned by Komodo. If you look at the output from `set`, it contains (among other things) the following:

```
PYTHONHOME=C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 5\lib\python
_KOMODO_HOSTUSERDATADIR=C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\ActiveState\KomodoEdit\5.1\host-host\
_KOMODO_VERUSERDATADIR=C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\ActiveState\KomodoEdit\5.1\
_XRE_USERAPPDATADIR=C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\ActiveState\KomodoEdit\5.1\host-host\XRE
```

I reported this bug [here at the ActiveState bug tracker](http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=83693).

Comment: Ok good to know that this wasn't a "feature" and there wasn't an easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

Oups! I've the same behavior on my Vista machine. I didn't see any settings for that feature and I think that this is a Komodo bug.

I though about a workaround: create a new command in the toolbox with "explorer %D" as command line. But it has the same problem :-(

Update: The workaround works if you put %D for StartIn. See the capture:

[alt text http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2972/komodoshowinexplorer.jpg](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2972/komodoshowinexplorer.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for working out a hack though I don't like to use the toolbox. I gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

What should your `sys.path` be instead?  It looks like Python is already on the path, but maybe you need other libraries there, too.

If you're missing some key directories, use `sys.path.append` in one of your Python modules.  If you need to move the directory of the Python interpreter (which may be necessary in order to get relative pathnames to work), use `os.chdir` as well.

Edit: It strikes me that you probably already know about those functions and that the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend going into Komodo Edit's Preferences >> Environment, and changing PYTHONHOME back to the original python install (e.g. c:\python27)